# Can't create new folders and files with Node JS with electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have created a MEAN stack application and I package it to a desktop application by **electron JS** , In there I am creating Folders and uploading files, But I am unable to create those files and folder by the desktop application, But when I run the project as a web application it will proceed perfectly fine,
Below Following Figure 1 is my Electron Main.Js file and Figure 2 is the Node js Creating folder method,

1. Figure 1 electron main.JS

   ```
   const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require("electron");
   var server = require("../wep-api/server");
   let win;

   function createWindow() {
     // Create the browser window.
     win = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 600,
       height: 670,
       fullscreen: true,
       icon: `file://${__dirname}/dist/assets/logo.png`,
     });
     win.setFullScreen(true);
     win.webContents.openDevTools();
     globalShortcut.register("ESC", () => {
       win.setFullScreen(false);
     });
     win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html`);

     win.setMenu(null);
     // uncomment below to open the DevTools.
     // win.webContents.openDevTools()

     // Event when the window is closed.
     win.on("closed", function () {
       win = null;
     });
   }

   // Create window on electron intialization
   app.on("ready", createWindow);

   // Quit when all windows are closed.
   app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
     // On macOS specific close process
     if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
       app.quit();
     }
   });

   app.on("activate", function () {
     // macOS specific close process
     if (win === null) {
       createWindow();
     }
   });
   ```
2. Figure 2 Node js folder creating method

   ```
    function (req, res) {
     const folderreation = new folderCreation(req.body);
     var saveFolder = folderreation.save();
     if (saveFolder) {
    let str = req.body.name.replace(/\s+/g, "_");

   const dir = "./file/" + str;
   console.log(dir);
   if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
     fs.mkdirSync(
       dir,
       {
         recursive: true,
       },
       function (err, result) {
         if (err) {
           console.log(err);
         }
       }
     );
   ```

Please kindly help with this problem Thank you

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Shall we have call

Answer (score 0):

I have Resolved a solution, Below is my explanation for that.

```
let str = req.body.name.replace(/\s+/g, "_"); 
const dir = "./file/" + str;
```

Setup the actual path, const dir = "You have to setup the actual path" + str;